# How to remove spaces in between from a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I need to remove the spaces in between.

For example: `"000 111 2222"`

And I'd live to have: `"0001112222"`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck

Comment: You could try something like `"000 111 2222".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")` but I hope there's a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "000 111 2222"
let newString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
print(newString)
```